# connect-pnponline fails with "The remote name could not be resolved"

Tags: powershell, proxy, sharepoint-online, azure-vm

I have a powershell script that is supposed to run on azure devops pipeline. The pipeline is in turn on a self-hosted VM (Azure VM) behind a proxy. The agent is service agent. Proxy configuration is also set. The following snippet fails:

```
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 
$ConfigInfo.GroupEmail.ToString().Trim(), ($ConfigInfo.GroupPassword.ToString().Trim() | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $Key) -Verbose

$Connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $ConfigInfo.Alu.AluSharePointUrl.ToString().Trim() -Credential $Credential -ReturnConnection -Verbose
```

with "The remote name could not be resolved". I checked the following link:

[Run a self-hosted agent behind a web proxy][1]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

And under the section **How the agent handles the proxy within a build or release job** it says the following:

*"The agent exposes proxy configuration via environment variables for every task execution. Task authors need to use azure-pipelines-task-lib methods to retrieve proxy configuration and handle the proxy within their task."*

Even you retrieve the proxy information, how do you feed this information to to the **Connect-PnPOnline**